Would building a forked blockchain on matic and combined with Redis have advantages over one thats not got Redis infrastructure?
I'm building a huge NFT data platform and I was wondering if having Redis and Redis AI would be a benefit or not for this project? I was implementing Redis to take the load away from the blockchain and to make it faster. I am looking at RedisAi to add searchable features.
Thanks a lot
All the best
Jayden
All testing as of this point in time.
